# Separate inconsistent seprated names

Tags: r, text, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data set with brand names like this:

```
Brand = data.frame(Brand = c("Nike, Adidas", "Nike Shoes", "Nike, New Balance, etc.", "Adidas, Nike, Reebok, Reebok Nike"))
```

The goal is to get each distinct brand name in one column. The problem is that the names are not separated consistently (e.g. some are separated by a comma, others by white space). So it´s not clear if a separation by white space is a separation between two brands (e.g. Nike Adidas) or between a brand name (e.g. New Balance). Is there a way to do this in R? For now  try to solve it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)

Brands %>%
  separate(Brand, into = c(LETTERS[(seq(1, 10))]), sep = ",") %>%
  select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0) 


          A            B       C            D
1       Nike       Adidas    <NA>         <NA>
2 Nike Shoes         <NA>    <NA>         <NA>
3       Nike  New Balance    etc.         <NA>
4     Adidas         Nike  Reebok  Reebok Nike
```

Some Brands are not in their own column (e.g. Nike in column D). If I now separate the names by white space I get some issues (e.g. Shoes, or New Balance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `split.default` to split alternate columns and create a named vector using first column of each group as names and second column as value after dropping `NA` values.

```
out <- lapply(split.default(weights, gl(ncol(weights)/2, 2)), function(x) {
   inds = !is.na(x[[2]])
   setNames(x[[2]][inds], x[[1]][inds])
})
names(out) <- names(weights)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]

#$RECAGE
#      1       2       3       4 
#0.12195 0.33841 0.35823 0.18140 

#$RECQ3
#      1       2       3       4 
#0.21325 0.24372 0.25057 0.29246 

#$Q3A
#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
#0.1327231 0.1617086 0.0480549 0.0259344 0.0076278 0.0274600 0.0785660 
#        8         9        10        11        12        13        14 
#0.0167811 0.0922960 0.2212052 0.0511060 0.0122044 0.0434783 0.0213577 
#       15        16 
#0.0358505 0.0236461 

#$Q5_1_REC
#       1        2        3        4 
#0.554116 0.205030 0.166921 0.073933 

#$Q5_2_REC
#      1       2       3       4 
#0.59237 0.13969 0.13206 0.13588
```

Comment: Thank you very much but the names `("RECAGE", "Q3A", "Q5_1_REC", "Q5_2_REC")` are not the set in the list (e.g. 1 must be named as "RECAGE" etc.)... but I think i will fix this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `map2` by subsetting the columns with a recycling logical vector

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(weights[c(TRUE, FALSE)], weights[c(FALSE, TRUE)], ~ {
       i1 <- !is.na(.x)
       set_names(.y[i1], .x[i1])
  })

#$RECAGE
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.1219512 0.3384146 0.3582317 0.1814024 

#$RECQ3
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.2132521 0.2437167 0.2505712 0.2924600 

#$Q3A
#          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12 
#0.132723112 0.161708619 0.048054920 0.025934401 0.007627765 0.027459954 0.078565980 0.016781083 0.092295957 0.221205187 0.051106026 0.012204424 
#         13          14          15          16 
#0.043478261 0.021357742 0.035850496 0.023646072 

#$Q5_1_REC
#         1          2          3          4 
#0.55411585 0.20503049 0.16692073 0.07393293 

#$Q5_2_REC
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.5923664 0.1396947 0.1320611 0.1358779
```

---

We could also do this programmatically by capturing the pattern in the names and split it to a `list` of named vectors

```
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)
weights %>%
     mutate(rn = row_number())  %>%
     rename_at(vars(-rn), ~
           str_replace(., "_Q", ":Q") %>% 
             {case_when(str_detect(., ":") ~ .,
                TRUE ~ str_c(., ":A"))}) %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_sep=":",
        names_to = c("group", ".value"), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
     split(.$group) %>% 
     map(~ select(., A, Q) %>% 
            deframe)
#$Q3A
#          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12 
#0.132723112 0.161708619 0.048054920 0.025934401 0.007627765 0.027459954 0.078565980 0.016781083 0.092295957 0.221205187 0.051106026 0.012204424 
#         13          14          15          16 
#0.043478261 0.021357742 0.035850496 0.023646072 

#$Q5_1_REC
#         1          2          3          4 
#0.55411585 0.20503049 0.16692073 0.07393293 

#$Q5_2_REC
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.5923664 0.1396947 0.1320611 0.1358779 

#$RECAGE
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.1219512 0.3384146 0.3582317 0.1814024 

#$RECQ3
#        1         2         3         4 
#0.2132521 0.2437167 0.2505712 0.2924600
```